# DataSource Attribute with Connection String to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, datasource

I'm trying to create a DataSource using the DataSource attribute, like in the next example:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Data Source=.\\153.71.88.80;Database=LoadData_For_R10Core_10_5_Final_Extended;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", "Products", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void GetProducts()
{
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

> The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.

What is the correct format to create the connection string in order to be able to connect to the SQL server. Also, I have ODBC connection on that machine, so if there is a way to use the connection of ODBC I will prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a default instance of SQL Server, `DataSource` should be `.` *or* `153.71.88.80`, not both.  Also, drop the `\\` separating them.

If you use an IP or hostname, be sure that:

- TCP/IP is enabled in the SQL Server's configuration.
- TCP port 1433 (or a non-default port you may've set) for SQL Server is not firewall-blocked.

If the target SQL Server is local, I would just use `.` - less trouble.

Comment: I changed the connection string to:

[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Data Source=153.71.88.80;Database=LoadData_For_R10Core_10_5_Final_Extended;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", "Products", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

But got exactly the same error

Comment: Did you make sure TCP/IP is enabled? Can you connect with SSMS?

Answer (score -1):

Well, for me was hard to find the real way to undertood how to configure DDT.
Here, I found what a think is a great explanation about the structure needed:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2006/01/10/511030.aspx

and here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx

I am using SQL Server, and I don´t have Access, so, usin the general example from Microsoft, this is the way this worked for me (VB.Net):

```
< TestMethod() > 
< DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True", "AccountTest", DataAccessMethod.Sequential) >

Public Sub AddIntegerHelper_DataDrivenValues_AllShouldPass()   <br>
    Dim target As New CheckingAccount()   <br>
    Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tscntx.DataRow("FirstNumber"))   <br>
    Dim y As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tscntx.DataRow("SecondNumber"))  <br>
    Dim expected As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tscntx.DataRow("Sum"))  <br>
    Dim actual As Integer = target.AddIntegerHelper(x, y)  <br>
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)  <br>
End Sub  <br>
```

Change `{localhost}` for your sql server name or the IP server (i.e. 192.18.130.26). 
I hope this helps.